# Stop Thunderbird from spam filtering

Tags: email, thunderbird, spam-prevention

I am using Thunderbird version 38.5 as an email client and it apparently keeps routing messages to a "Spam" folder. I have all junk settings turned off for this account (as shown below), but it still keeps routing messages to the spam folder for some reason. How can I turn off the spam filtering in Thunderbird?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Even if junk filtering is disabled in Thunderbird, there are two other ways that new emails can show up in the "Spam" folder:

- other email clients
- the server handling the emails

### Other Email Clients

If you log in to your email from any other clients like a mobile phone app or another computer, the spam filters on those clients may be moving emails from the inbox to your "Spam" folder.

You'll have to turn off junk filtering in those clients as well.

### Your Email Server

Email servers can usually be configured to deliver suspected junk emails into the spam folder.

I noticed that your email provider is Zoho Mail from an MX lookup of the domain in your screenshot.  You can turn off spam filtering in Zoho Mail like shown in this screenshot:

[image: https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/how-to-turn-off-spam-filtering-for-zoho-mail]

<sup><sub>Source: https://help.zoho.com/portal/community/topic/how-to-turn-off-spam-filtering-for-zoho-mail</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching for an answer to this that works for months.

As a workaround, I have just **selected my inbox as the folder where Thunderbird sends spam**.

Nothing else has worked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It doesn't work :-(

Answer (score 0):

I was able to allow a specific sender by making a filter to move those messages from spam to inbox AFTER junk classification.